# get image with jquery by username

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox for entering username. I want to get user image if username exist.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
   <img id="avatar" src="default.jpg" alt="">
   <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
</form>
```

I want to check username image with javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#username").keyup(function (event) {
        var url = location.pathname 
                  +"/Images/avatars/" 
                  + event.target.value + ".jpg";

        $.get(url, {}, function (response) {

        });             
    });
</script>
```

If image exist, user image will appear in image box, but if not exist default image will appear.

But my get request did not work.

Comment: What was the status code your GET request returned?

Comment: If that is a login form, then isn't that a breach of security because you are informing people that the user actually exists and hence could be giving away a user name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Image [**onload**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onload) and [**onerror**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onerror) event.

```
$("#username").keyup(function (event) {
    var url = location.pathname 
              +"/Images/avatars/" 
              + event.target.value + ".jpg";
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function () { 
        $('#avatar').prop('src', url); //When load's sucessfully
    };
    img.onerror = function () { 
        $('#avatar').prop('src', 'default.jpg'); //When load's fails
    };            
});
```